# How to get list of Bitcoin Block Hashes by Block Number?

Tags: api, block, hash

Suppose I want to obtain the block hashes for all Bitcoin blocks numbered 1 through 50,000. What would be the best way to obtain this information? I could write a web scraper to pull it off web-based blockchain explorers but that would take forever to run.

Answer (score 5):

Easy enough with your own Bitcoin node.

```sh
for height in {1..500000}; do echo "$height `bitcoin-cli getblockhash $height`"; done
```